# How can I force the hamburger menu in Bootstrap on tablets at 991px wide?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

On the website https://weightlosspillsreviews.com I have a problem when displaying on tablet devices at 991px or less in viewport width. The problem is that the menu items get line breaks at that viewport breakpoint and I want to switch to the hamburger menu at that breakpoint.

When I tried overriding bootstrap.css, which has its breakpoint set to 767px, by putting the associated media queries into my style.css file and setting them to 991px, the whole top nav menu disappears rather than switching to the hamburger menu.

Here are the styles I put into style.css and adjusted:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .hidden-xs {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-inverse .visible-xs {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

But when that code is present, the whole menu disappears.

What am I missing here?

Comment: refer to this Link, I had the same issue and this thread helped me solve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853166/bootstrap-4-navbar-display-mobile-version-for-tablet

Comment: @Abdul Hanna that thread is for bootstrap 4. The website in question is using version 3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the website uses bootstrap 3.3.7. In later versions of bootstrap, this can be simply updated just by a class. You can go down that path of updating the bootstrap version if you want.

A quicker solution would be downloading a customized bootstrap style. Go to this link to customize your CSS: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

In the Grid System section update **@grid-float-breakpoint** to the width you want that navbar to collapse.

Comment: Thanks. I want to try these things but first need to get a staging site working to not break the live site. The getbootstrap.com solution seems extensive because this particular site, which I didn't make, has a lot of customized/deprecated unknowns. If I generate all of that and apply it, it's likely to break a "black box" site like this, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, if you have changed the bootstrap file then you'll break something by adding a new CSS. I would recommend using a tool to find the difference between the normal bootstrap and bootstrap with different breaking point and apply those changes to your current CSS.